# How can I make Gerrit apply the "verified" label?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity, gerrit

I added the `verified` label to `All-Projects`, but it doesn't seem to work with TeamCity. TeamCity says that it sent the message to Gerrit, but Gerrit still doesn't show the changeset as verified.

I replayed the command from TeamCity with a terminal and it was successful (but again, with no visible effect):

```
$ ssh teamcity@gerrit.local -p 29418 -t 'gerrit review --verified=+1 --message=http://localhost:8111/viewLog.html?buildId=646&tab=buildResultsDiv&buildTypeId=bt5 98b2ada339da6b3567a11db87442fa795ce5d8a1'
Connection to gerrit.local closed.
```

When I tried the same thing but with an invalid value (+2 instead of +1) to see what happens, I got, as expected, an error message:

```
$ ssh teamcity@gerrit.local -p 29418 -t 'gerrit review --verified=+2 --message=http://localhost:8111/viewLog.html?buildId=646&tab=buildResultsDiv&buildTypeId=bt5 98b2ada339da6b3567a11db87442fa795ce5d8a1'
Connection to gerrit.local closed.
fatal: "+2" must be in range -1..+1 for "--verified"
                                                    Connection to gerrit.local closed.
```

So the `--verified` status reaches Gerrit, it is read properly, but it seems it is not applied properly.

What can get in the way of Gerrit showing the Verified status?

**UPDATE** The user TeamCity appears as having been a reviewer, but it did not give any score for Verified.

Answer (score 0):

The user `teamcity` did not have permissions to set the label. I find it odd that Gerrit didn't say anything about that... I "solved" the problem by making `teamcity` an admin if has any permissions it needs or will ever need.